# How do I extract digits from a C string?

Tags: c, string, output, digit

I'm trying to make three simple c programs, but i'll limit this to only one of them since this first question is only specific to one. (Yeah this is hw in case you were curious.)

For this program, the goal is to create one that can take the string:

```
"BCC  6 T LL 8 9 *** & EXTRA@@@@@"
```

and output/print

```
"689"
```

The code i'll paste below is my sad attempt at this and really I got no results. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
printf("BCC  6 T LL 8 9 *** & EXTRA@@@@@\n");

char ch=getchar();  
while(ch!='\n')
    {
    if(isdigit(ch)|| ch!='*' || ch!='@')
        printf("%c", ch);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting `getchar()` to read in the line that you printed? Or is the user supposed to copy and paste the output?

Comment: I was going for the getchar() to read in the line, but it could have been either.

Comment: You do not need to apologize for being new to coding: everyone here has been there at some point.

Comment: Yeah you have a point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
    if (isdigit(ch) {
        printf("%c", ch);
    }
}
```

Your code had one serious problem: you were not calling `getchar()` inside the `while` loop. So it would just read one character and repeatedly process that same character. The other problem was your `if` condition -- the tests for `ch != '*' || ch != '@'` would be true for all the alphabetic and space characters. If you only want to print digits, there's no need for those tests.

As I mentioned in the comment, this will process what the user types, not what you print with `printf()`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do

```
while(ch!='\n')
    if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
        printf("%c",ch);
```

A neat and simple code.
No need to call a separate function `isdigit()`, when you use `ch >= '0'` it compares the **ASCII** value of the character and **'0'**
Once the condition hold true, your digit will be printed. Also there is `no need to check for '*' and '@'` , there can be more such special characters in a new string. How long can you put checks?